# Is there a better design practice than to add a new virtual function in base that is not implemented by all derived classes

Tags: c++, class, class-design

I have class hierarchy as shown below. It's a simplified version of actual code.

```
class Base
{
public :
   // user_define_type is a output parameter
   virtual void Fill(user_define_type);
}

class A : public Base
{
public :
    void Fill(user_define_type) override;
}
class B : public Base
{
public :
    void Fill(user_define_type) override;
}
```

I am overriding `Fill()` method as I need different formatting in both derived classes. Now I have to write one more class deriving from "Base" as it has common functionality. Now my problem is that new class will have to implement `Fill()` that will operate on different user defined type. As I am returning base class pointer from factory so new `Fill()` has to be virtual in base but that means I have to add it's definition in older classes "A" and "B" and throw not supported exception from them. This is not a good design. Any better design you guys can suggest ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a few options depending on what you're actually doing. Can you update your question with some actual code that shows what you're really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create a common base class for your user_defined_types in order to achieve this. I also think this could be a good place to use the [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.

Basically, you create

```
class user_defined_type_base 
{
    ...
}

class user_defined_type_derived : public user_defined_type_base
{
    ...
}

class DoSomething
{
    private:
        DoSomethingStrategy *strategy;

    public:
        DoSomething(DoSomethingStrategy *strategy) { this->strategy = strategy; }
        void Fill(user_defined_type_base *type) { this->strategy->Fill(type); }
}

class DoSomethingStrategy
{
    public:
        virtual void Fill(user_defined_type_base *obj) = 0;
}

class DoSomethingStrategyA : public DoSomethingStrategy
{
    public:
        void Fill(user_defined_type_base *obj)
        {
            ...
        }
}

class DoSomethingStrategyB : public DoSomethingStrategy
{
    public:
        void Fill(user_defined_type_base *obj)
        {
            ...
        }
}

class DoSomethingStrategyC : public DoSomethingStrategy
{
    public:
        void Fill(user_defined_type_base *obj)
        {
            ...
        }
}

void main()
{
    DoSomethingStrategy *strategy = new DoSomethingStragegyA();
    DoSomething *dosomething = new DoSomething(strategy);
    user_defined_type_base *type = new user_defined_type_base();
    dosomething->Fill(type);

    DoSomethingStrategy *strategyC = new DoSomethingStragegyC();
    DoSomething *dosomethingC = new DoSomething(strategyC);
    user_defined_type_base *typeC = new user_defined_type_derived();
    dosomethingC->Fill(typeC);
}
```